# Unable to make divs draggable with jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

have: jquery 2.1.3, chrome

the following code displays 2 divs, connect them (so jsPlumb does work), but the divs are non draggable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .drag-me {
            width: 230px;
            height: 250px;
            margin: 15px;

            background-color: #29e;
            color: white;

            border-radius: 1em;
            padding: 20px;

            -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
            transform: translate(0px, 0px);
        }

        .drag-me::before {
            content: "#" attr(id);
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:white;margin:0px auto;}
        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#669;background-color:#e8edff;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}
        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aabcfe;color:#039;background-color:#b9c9fe;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;}


    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="drag-me" id="draggable1"></div>
<div class="drag-me" id="draggable2"></div>



</body>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jsPlumb/dist/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.7.4.js"></script>

<script>

    jsPlumb.ready(function() {
        jsPlumb.draggable($("#draggable1"));
        jsPlumb.draggable($("#draggable2"));
        jsPlumb.connect({source:"draggable1", target:"draggable2"});

    });


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1. Required Imports:](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html#imports)

jQuery UI 1.7.x or higher (if you wish to support drag and drop). Always remember to check that the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI you are using are compatible.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="PATH_TO/jquery.jsPlumb-1.7.4-min.js"></script>
```

[2. Required CSS:](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html#dragging)

You must set `position:absolute` on elements that you intend to be draggable. The reasoning for this is that all libraries implement dragging by manipulating the `left` and `top` properties of an element's `style` attribute.

```
.drag-me {
    position: absolute;
    width: 230px;
    ...
}
```